# $\operatorname{Im} f$ is a submodule of a R-module where $f$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

There is a statement:

> If $R$ is a ring and $f:A\rightarrow B$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, then $\,\operatorname{Im} f$ is a submodule of $B$.

I am confused about if for any $r\in R$, the $rf(a)\in B$. Because maybe I can not get the $r'$ such that $f(r')=r$. So how can I prove it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A homorphism is a linear map, so $af(r)=f(\dots)$.

Comment: Got it, thank you.@Bernard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $a,b\in A$ and $r\in R$,
then $f(a)+f(b) =f(a+b)\in Im(f)$
and $r\cdot f(a) = f(r\cdot a)\in Im(f)$.
So $Im(f)$ is closed under addition and $R$-multiplication.